# Copying certain columns VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working VBA macro which copies from one spreadsheet 'AverageEarnings' to another 'Sheet1', under the condition that Column AO has the word 'UNGRADED' in it. The macro copies the entirety of these conditional rows to Sheet1. I am looking to copy columns B and C ('AverageEarnings') to columns A and B ('Sheet1'). How do I amend this.

```
 Sub UngradedToSHEET1()

' UngradedToSHEET1 Macro
'
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim stringToFind As String

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("AverageEarnings")

    stringToFind = "UNGRADED"

    With ws1
        'Remove all filters from spreadsheet to prevent loss of information.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRow = .Range("AO" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Find a specific column.

        With .Range("AO1:AO" & lRow) ' This is the row where GRADED or UNGRADED is specified.
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & stringToFind & "*" 'Filter specific information.
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        'Remove spreadsheet filters again.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then    ' Find a blank row after A1.
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If
        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `How do I amend this.`? Please explain what problem are you facing and what have you tried to solve that problem.

Comment: My problem is locating what I need to amend in order to copy specific columns. I am assuming that it is within this line -                                            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow      The entire row function perhaps needs to be amended to a specific cells function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line copies the entire row:

`Set copyFrom = 
  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow`

You will need to change `EntireRow` to just copy the columns you want, probably something like:

`Set copyFrom = 
  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range(.Cells(1,2),.Cells(1,3))`

Hope this helps, I can't check this right now.

Comment: Great didn't see this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.